# Joining keys/values from C++ STL associative containers

Tags: c++, string, stl, join, containers

I have a join function that operates on STL strings.  I want to be able to apply it to to a container like this:

```
getFoos(const std::multimap<std::string, std::string>& map) {
    return join_values(",", map.equal_range("foo"));
```

In other words, find all matching keys in the collection and concatenate the values into a single string with the given separator.  Same thing with `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` for a range of keys, `begin()`/`end()` for the entire contents of the container, etc..

The closest I could get is the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct join_range_values : public T::const_iterator::value_type::second_type {
    typedef typename T::const_iterator::value_type pair_type;
    typedef typename pair_type::second_type value_type;

    join_range_values(const value_type& sep) : sep(sep) { }

    void operator()(const pair_type& p) {
        // this function is actually more complex...
        *this += sep;
        *this += p.second;
    }
private:
    const value_type sep;
};

template <typename T>
typename T::const_iterator::value_type::second_type join_values(
    const typename T::const_iterator::value_type::second_type& sep,
    const std::pair<typename T::const_iterator, typename T::const_iterator>& range) {
    return std::for_each(range.first, range.second, join_range_values<T>(sep));
}
```

(I realize that inheriting from `std::string` or whatever the key/value types are is generally considered a bad idea, but I'm not overloading or overriding any functions, and I don't need a virtual destructor.  I'm doing so only so that I can directly use the result of `for_each` without having to define an implicit conversion operator.)

There are very similar definitions for `join_range_keys`, using `first_type` and `p.first` in place of `second_type` and `p.second`.  I'm assuming a similar definition will work for joining `std::set` and `std::multiset` keys, but I have not had any need for that.

I can apply these functions to containers with strings of various types.  Any combination of `map` and `multimap` with any combination of `string` and `wstring` for the key and value types seems to work:

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string, std::string> NNMap;
const NNMap col;
const std::string a = join_keys<NNMap>(",", col.equal_range("foo"));
const std::string b = join_values<NNMap>(",", col.equal_range("foo"));

typedef std::multimap<std::string, std::wstring> NWMap;
const NWMap wcol;
const std::string c = join_keys<NWMap>(",", wcol.equal_range("foo"));
const std::wstring d = join_values<NWMap>(L",", wcol.equal_range("foo"));

typedef std::multimap<std::wstring, std::wstring> WWMap;
const WWMap wwcol;
const std::wstring e = join_keys<WWMap>(L",", wwcol.equal_range(L"foo"));
const std::wstring f = join_values<WWMap>(L",", wwcol.equal_range(L"foo"));
```

This leaves me with several questions:

1. Am I missing some easier way to accomplish the same thing?  The function signature especially seems overly complicated.
2. Is there a way to have `join_values` automatically deduce the template parameter type so that I don't need to call it with `join_values<MapType>` every time?
3. How can I refactor the `join_values` and `join_keys` functions and functors to avoid duplicating most of the code?

I did find a slightly simpler solution based on `std::accumulate`, but it seems to require two complete copy operations of the entire string for each element in the range, so it's much less efficient, as far as I can tell.

```
template <typename T>
struct join_value_range_accum : public T::const_iterator::value_type::second_type
{
    typedef typename T::const_iterator::value_type::second_type value_type;
    join_value_range_accum(const value_type& sep) : sep(sep) {}

    using value_type::operator=;
    value_type operator+(const typename T::const_iterator::value_type& p)
    {
        return *this + sep + p.second;
    }
private:
    const value_type sep;
};

typedef std::multimap<std::string, std::string> Map;
Map::_Pairii range = map.equal_range("foo");
std::accumulate(range.first, range.second, join_value_range_accum<Map>(","));
```

Comment: Oh boy, I need to digest this first...hold on!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The STL algorithms typically work with iterators, not containers, so I would suggest something like the following.

```
template <typename T, typename Iterator>
T join(
    const T sep,
    Iterator b,
    Iterator e)
{
    T t;

    while (b != e)
        t = t + *b++ + sep;

    return t;
}
```

Then, you need an iterator that will pull out keys or values. Here's an example:

```
template <typename Key, typename Iterator>
struct KeyIterator
{
    KeyIterator(
        Iterator i)
        :_i(i)
    {
    }

    KeyIterator operator++()
    {
        ++_i;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(
        KeyIterator ki)
    {
        return _i = ki._i;
    }

    typename Iterator::value_type operator*()
    {
        return _i->first;
    }
};
```

How to use:

```
string s = join(",", KeyIterator(my_map.begin()), KeyIterator(my_map.end()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI for anyone interested, I came to the following solution based on keraba's input.

I did have to make some changes, specifically:

1. Making the `T` template parameter for the separator string a dependent type name so that the compiler would infer it automatically (allowing quoted literals to be automatically converted into string objects)
2. Using a functor derived from string to get around the fact that the dependent name declared in the iterator is `const`, so a local temporary defined in `join()` ends up being `const` and therefore unmodifiable.

---

```
template <typename I>
struct MapKeyIterator : public I
{
    typedef typename I::value_type::first_type value_type;
    MapKeyIterator(I const &i) : I(i) { }
    value_type const & operator*() const { return (*this)->first; }
};

template <typename I>
struct MapValueIterator : public I
{
    typedef typename I::value_type::second_type value_type;
    MapValueIterator(I const &i) : I(i) { }
    value_type const & operator*() const { return (*this)->second; }
};

template <typename I>
struct join_functor : public I::value_type
{
    typedef typename I::value_type value_type;
    join_functor(value_type const &sep) : sep(sep) { }
    void operator()(value_type const &s)
    {
        *this += s;
        *this += sep;
    }
private:
    const value_type sep;
};

template <typename I>
typename I::value_type join(typename I::value_type const &sep, I beg, I const &end)
{
    return std::for_each(beg, end, join_functor<I>(sep));
}

template <typename I>
typename I::value_type::first_type join_keys(typename I::value_type::first_type const &sep, I const &beg, I const &end)
{
    return join(sep, MapKeyIterator<I>(beg), MapKeyIterator<I>(end));
}
template <typename I>
typename I::value_type::first_type join_keys(typename I::value_type::first_type const &sep, std::pair<I, I> const &ip)
{
    return join(sep, MapKeyIterator<I>(ip.first), MapKeyIterator<I>(ip.second));
}
template <typename I>
typename I::value_type::second_type join_values(typename I::value_type::second_type const &sep, I const &beg, I const &end)
{
    return join(sep, MapValueIterator<I>(beg), MapValueIterator<I>(end));
}
template <typename I>
typename I::value_type::second_type join_values(typename I::value_type::second_type const &sep, std::pair<I, I> const &ip)
{
    return join(sep, MapValueIterator<I>(ip.first), MapValueIterator<I>(ip.second));
}
```

This allows for:

```
join_keys(",", map.equal_range("foo"));
join_values(",", map.equal_range("foo"));
join_values(",", map.begin(), map.end());
```

as well as:

```
join(",", set.lower_bound("f"), set.upper_bound("g"));
```

with containers based on either `std::string` or `std::wstring`.

This is still fairly complex, but it solves items 2 and 3 from my original post and it does seem to fit much better with the design of the STL.